# Quarkus Custom authorization interceptors or filter

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I have a Quarkus microservice doing authentication and authorization with Keycloak using quarkus-oidc and quarkus-keycloak-authorization extensions.

when i use quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer, reader & writer interceptors and container request & container response filters and exception mapper (with disable proactive) not working on 401 error. do you have any idea??

Comment: Hello, you need to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if you want to get some answers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.